# Populate input from another input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a search function where on click, I want it to parse any input received from the search bar I created to react-table's search bar respectively.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-microservice-ywyt2

Comment: What do u mean by parse the input??

Comment: Do you want to display the table rows based on the searchKey??

Comment: instead of showing the react-table's search function, I want to hide it and make it look like it's searched from my search bar.

Comment: You are basically taking of `onKeyup` event?

Comment: you can remove `filterable` prop and handle search manually

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty how do you do that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-dawn-0zmwk go through this sandbox if it helps, I will explain clearly in an answer

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty It works but can it work with the ```<select>``` function as well?

Comment: do you mean it has to filter by gender and organisation too??

Comment: Yes, because my actual database is much larger so it would need more filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually filter the data by using `Array.filter` method, for various conditions and priorities.

You can refer to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-dawn-0zmwk) sandbox for basic implementation of it.

It is basic implementation and you need to make changes to it according to your data

the basic fucntionality i have written on `handleClick` method is

```
handleClick(e) {
  const regex = new RegExp(this.state.searchkey, "i");
  let filteredData = data.filter(item => regex.test(item.name));
  if (this.state.dept) {
    filteredData = filteredData.filter(item => item.dept === this.state.dept);
  }
  if (this.state.type) {
    filteredData = filteredData.filter(item => item.type === this.state.type);
  }
  this.setState({ filteredData });
}
```

PS: this is not a perfect logic Can be optimised

Comment: how would I go about if I want to filter multiple columns using the same search key?